# Serilog console when running as systemd

Tags: .net-core, systemd, serilog

I have a .Net core 5.0 application that uses the Serilog console sink to log. A part of the application starts a Prometheus metrics endpoint, this part is not integrated with Serilog and prints also to console.

When running as a docker both serilog and the endpoint prints to console.

When I install as a systemd service in ubuntu 20.04 LTS I see only the Prometheus logs, no Serilog.

app.service

```
[Unit]
Description=App1
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=appuser
Group=appuser
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/app
EnvironmentFile=/usr/local/bin/app/app.env
ExecStart=dotnet /usr/local/bin/app/app.dll
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Running `journalctl -f -u app` shows only the Prometheus logs. Is there a way to configure serilog to work with systemd?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration error, the application was still trying to log to file. Once that was fixed serilog console logging shows up in systemd journal just fine.